# Using login data to skip over search

Tags: custom-fields, search-results

I have set up a bunch of my contacts with a group of custom fields that can have multiple entries.
I set up a profile to list out these custom fields, however, it is asking me to enter search criteria before listing the entries.  I would like it to automatically use the logged in users information to search on it and display only their entries - how can I do this?

TIA
Norm

Comment: Norm - i have read this twice and haven't grasped the requirement/intention. One option is to replicate a simplified version on one of the demo sites then folks can look at what you mean (just try and avoid doing it just before they reset the site which happens every 24 hours)

Comment: Ok, I set up a small demo in the http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org server.  Check out user john test1 (test1@no.org) and then check the tab for the custom data.  It has multiple records.  When this user is logged into the web site as a user/subscriber, I want him to be able to  go to a page with their data on it listed out.  Right now when the user goes to that page they have to enter a searchable value in a searchable field to get the results listing.

Comment: you might need to flesh this out more. when you say "Right now when the user goes to that page" i am not sure 'which' page you mean. since i take it you don't mean http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fview&reset=1&cid=203

Comment: and sorry if i am slow to grasp this. i could give you an instant recipe (i think) for Drupal, but don't know WP tricks - so just trying to help you finesse your Question to improve chance that someone who speaks WordPress can help ;-)

Comment: To close this out, I have actually written a custom PHP script to do this for me in a nice table format.  I inject the PHP using a wordpress plugin call XYZ PHP Code and it works great.

Comment: Norm - would be good if you add this as an Answer

Answer (score 2):

To close this out, I have actually written a custom PHP script to do this for me in a nice table format. I inject the PHP using a wordpress plugin call XYZ PHP Code and it works great.

you can get the script here: http://txt.do/d01fm

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  Are you happy to share the code to help others?